# Graphite docker image does not accept messages from Spring boot

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, graphite, statsd

There is a problem with Graphite Docker images I try to run on my PC. Containers start up gracefully but I'm not able to send any message so that it would be displayed under "Metrics" tab. Volumes Mounting doesn't help either. Default storage-schema.conf should accept all messages.
The message used for testing is such:

> echo "test.bash.stats 42 `date +%s`" | nc localhost 2003.

Moreover, most of the time (but not always) after sending above listed message "400 Bad request" error is responded.

Following images has been tested:
https://hub.docker.com/r/hopsoft/graphite-statsd/
https://hub.docker.com/r/kamon/grafana_graphite/
Any ideas, I'm missing something to configure additionally?

Comment: The problem was very simple. Don't have to go deep into research - just use correct port, not Graphite GUI port...

Answer (score 0):

Despite the above explained issue there is is question related to Spring Boot Metrics export to Graphite over StatsD. 
As described here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html in section **49.8.3 Example: Export to Statsd** there is a requirement only to add com.timgroup:java-statsd-client as dependency and add property **spring.metrics.export.statsd.host**. 
Unfortunately nothing is send to Graphite (docker image running on local PC https://github.com/kamon-io/docker-grafana-graphite). I have checked network with Wireshark (udp.port=8125). Is there maybe something missing to add into Spring boot project with metrics?